# Delete the meeting from User calendar

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are using exchange server 2010. I can use the search-mailbox cmdlet for deleting the meeting from user mailbox as mentioned below

```
search-mailbox -searchquery "kind:meetings from:$recipient" -targetmailbox $mailid -targetfolder "REPORT" -deletecontent -force
```

My question here is How to send the cancellation mail to attendees after deleting the meetings from the organizer mailbox?

Regards,

Sankar M

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Search-mailbox is a server-side/adminstrative function.  Cancelling a meeting is a client-side/user function.  If you want to send cancellation notices, then you need to do a normal user meeting cancellation using EWS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to cancel meetings from today using outlook as com object.

```
    $outlookApplication = New-Object -ComObject 'Outlook.Application'
    $namespace  = $outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    print("Define Start/End time for filtering existing meetings..")
    $Start = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString() + " 11:59 PM"
    $End = (Get-Date).AddDays(+1).ToShortDateString() + " 12:01 AM"
    print("Start time: " + $Start)
    print("End time: " + $End)
    print("Create meeting filter..")
    $Filter = "[MessageClass]='IPM.Appointment' AND [Start] > '$Start' AND [End] < '$End'  
    AND     [IsRecurring] = '$False'"
    print("Extract all meetings...")
    $olFolderCalendar = 9
    $Appointments = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
    $Appointments.Sort("[Start]")
    $Appointments.IncludeRecurrences = $false
    print("Process all meeting from today..")
    foreach ($Appointment in $Appointments.Restrict($Filter) ) {
        print("Process meeeting.. Subject: " + $Appointment.Subject)
        print("Required resources: " + $Appointment.Resources)
        print("Meeting start time: " + $Appointment.Start)
        print("Meeting end time: " + $Appointment.End)
        print("Cancell meeting..")
        $Appointment.meetingstatus = 5
        # olMeeting 1   The meeting has been scheduled.
        # olMeetingCanceled 5   The scheduled meeting has been cancelled.
        # olMeetingReceived 3   The meeting request has been received.
        # olMeetingReceivedAndCanceled  7   The scheduled meeting has been cancelled but 
         still appears on the user's calendar.
        # olNonMeeting  0   An Appointment item without attendees has been scheduled. This 
         status can be used to set up holidays on a calendar.
        $Appointment.Send()
        print("Delete meeting..")
        $Appointment.Delete()
    }
```